# Python Tkinter - Protocol Handler on CLose Window Event

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, window, protocols

How will I overwrite the exit function a Top Level Window if the user clicks on the X button at the upper right of the window? I have tried this code with no fortune.

```
def chat():
global root, private_chat, chat_list_window, chat_list, ip, port, address,username
global private_chat_window, private_chat_messages, private_chat_label, private_chat_entry
address = (ip,int(port))


invited_client = chat_list[len(chat_list) -1].get(chat_list[len(chat_list) -1].curselection())

private_chat_window.append(tk.Toplevel(root))
length = len(private_chat_window)
private_chat_window[length-1].title("Private Chat with '" +  invited_client[2] + "'" )


private_chat_messages.append(Listbox(private_chat_window[length -1], width=80, height=30))
private_chat_messages[length-1].grid(row=1,column=1, columnspan=3,rowspan=1)
private_chat_messages[length-1].insert(END, "Inviting client '" + invited_client[2] + "'for a private chat...")


private_chat_label.append(ttk.Label(private_chat_window[length -1], text='Message Entry Box : '))
private_chat_label[length-1].grid(row=2,column=1)


private_chat_entry.append(ttk.Entry(private_chat_window[length -1] , width=60))
private_chat_entry[length-1].grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan = 2)    


daemon = Pyro4.Daemon()       
uri_str = daemon.register(Messaging())      

private_chat_window[length-1].bind('<KeyPress>', lambda event: private_chat_onkeypress(event,private_chat_messages[length -1], private_chat_entry[length -1], uri_str = uri_str) )
chat_list_window[len(chat_list_window)-1].destroy()

s.sendto(str.encode(":::PrivateChatInvitation:::" + '<' + username + '><' +  str(uri_str) + '>' + json.dumps(invited_client)) , address)


Thread(target = daemon.requestLoop).start()
Thread(target=check_successful_connection(uri_str, private_chat_messages[length -1])).start()

#EXIT
private_chat_window[length -1].protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing(private_chat_window[length -1]))
private_chat_window[length -1].mainloop()


def on_closing(window_instance):

    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
         window_instance.destroy()
```

The protocol handler doesn't  work on the top level window but when attached to the root main window, it works fine. Below is the code:

def render_gui():
    global root
    global prev_key
    global listbox, label1, entry1, username
    prev_key = 0

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Welcome Client '" + username + "'" )


listbox = Listbox(root, width=80, height=30)      
listbox.grid(row=1,column=1, columnspan=5,rowspan=3)


vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=listbox.yview)
hsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=listbox.xview)
vsb.grid(row=1, column=4,rowspan = 3, sticky='ns')
hsb.grid(row=3, column=0,rowspan = 1, columnspan=5, sticky = 'wes')


#Menubar

menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Private Chat",command=private_chat_threader) #Hmppp
menubar.add_cascade(label="Options", menu= filemenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)

listbox.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set,xscrollcommand=hsb.set)

label1 = ttk.Label(root, text='Message Entry Box : ')
label1.grid(row=4,column=1)

entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=60)
entry1.grid(row=4, column=2)    

root.geometry('490x520')
root.bind('<KeyPress>', onKeyPress)

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing(root))
root.mainloop()
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your code can work on the root window or on the `Toplevel`. The `protocol` method requires that you pass in a *callable* (ie: a reference to a function). Instead, you're calling `on_closing(root)` immediately and then passing the result to the protocol handler.

You need to be calling `protocol` like this:

```
private_chat_window[length -1].protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
```

If you need to pass arguments, you can use either `lambda` or `functools.partial` like you would for any other callback. For example:

```
private_chat_window[length-1].protocol(
    "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 
    lambda: on_closing(private_chat_window[length -1])
)
```